# Matlab Convert to Double Precision from Image

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

I am self teaching/exploring Matlab.
I am working on doing some basic image manipulation and analysis.

The tutorial I'm following converts an RGB image to the LaB color space.

```
 RGB = imread('Images/cow.jpg');
    cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
    lab_he = applycform(RGB,cform);
    imshow(lab_he);
```

Everything works fine until this point. The next step is to classify the colors in the a b color space using k-means clustering.   This was the code snippet provided.=:

```
ab = double(lab_he(:,:,2:3));
nrows = size(ab,1);
ncols = size(ab,2);
ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,2);
nColors = 3;
```

Can someone explain to me what is being passed to the double() function?
What is lab_he(:,:,2:3) parameter/function doing? I realize it is converting something to a double precision value. I just don't know what is being converted.

Here is the tutorial I am following: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/color-based-segmentation-using-k-means-clustering.html

Comment: What happens if you do not convert it to double, i.e. `ab = lab_he(:,:,2:3);`?

Comment: See the documentation of [**`colon`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html)

Comment: Wow, probably should have just looked there first.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the tutorial, the lab_he variable was created with the applycform function.  According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/applycform.html), this function is passed up to three values.  So, the double function receives the he and cform parameters as well as the second to third spaces of some vector for class support.  Good luck with your project!

Edited to fix hyperlink.